# IIS Express and VS 2015 bypassing my index

Tags: visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I do not understand why this is but when I try to debug with VS2015 sometimes it will go to my index action (where it is determined if the user is authorized or not) and then supposed to go to a Request action.  Most often it tries to go directly to the Request action without ever hitting the Index.  Why does it do this?  It is frustrating!

Comment: show us some code

Comment: I don't know what good code would do - as I said it completely bypasses the Index action most of the time.  When I add a breakpoint, it may work ok, but sometimes it doesn't.  Is there some setting in the project or IIS Express that I need to change?

Comment: well the Index is specified action, if your URL does not intend to hit Index it won't go into it. It doesn't have to go through Index for all the requests

Comment: @PawełŁukasik This only happens when I do not make a code change.  If I make a change to the code, it recompiles and works as it should.  But if I just execute in debug mode it attempts to go to the last action.  Why is that?

Comment: check what are your settings in the `Web` tab of your project settings. Is there something odd?

Comment: @PawełŁukasik  Yes!  That was the problem.  I had "Current Page" checked instead of {Specific Page" without an entry.  Give me an answer to get credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your project settings. If `Current Page` is set it might execute the Action that your in.

[image: VS project settings]